# was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on this code I try to remove item from linked list but I couldn't understand what is that error. Error is delnode was not declared in this scope. I build it eclipse and visual studio but error is still continue.

```
char name[10];

void delnode(char name[], NODEPTR  *head)
{
    NODEPTR save, prev;
    prev=*head;
    save=prev->n;
    while (save!=*head && strcmp(name ,save->info)>0)
    {
        prev = save;
        save = save->n;
    }
    if (save==*head || strcmp(name,save->info)<0) printf("%s Not found",name);
    else
    {
        if (prev->n==*head) *head=prev;
        prev->n = save->n;
        free(save);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Write a name to delete it");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    delnode(name, head); //Error delnode was not declared in this scope
}
```

Addition;
Guys thank you for your help and now this it gave this error;

Multiple markers at this line

```
- Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void delnode(char *, node * *) '

- cannot convert ‘NODEPTR {aka node*}’ to ‘node**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void delnode(char*, 

 node**)’
- Line breakpoint: lab.cpp [line: 87]
```

in line 87

Comment: Move function before main...

Comment: error still continue.

Comment: I have answered your New question below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the declaration of `delnode` before it is used:

```
void delnode(char name[], NODEPTR  *head); // declaration

char name[10];

int main()
{
  // as before
}

void delnode(char name[], NODEPTR  *head)
{
  // as before
}
```

After fixing that, you still need to fix this line in `main`:

```
delnode(name, head);
```

At this point, `head` has not been declared.

Comment: I write it before main now it gave interesting error I edit the question above.

Comment: @user2265473 `head` is not declared at the time it is used in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `delnode` without the compiler knowing what it is.

In order to fix this, either move the `delnode` function before `main` where you are using it, or declare a prototype like this (which is prefereably):

```
void delnode(char name[], NODEPTR  *head);
```

Answer (score 0):

After function move you seems to have different error now
 Try passing address of head node using `&`

```
delnode(name, & head);
```